# ¿Cómo insertar el caracter ℓ en Latex?

Tags: latex

No sé que código poner para insertar este tipo de l en Látex.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, lo respondieron [aquí](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248538/creating-curvy-symbol-for-letter-l/248540).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @carlosabcs ponlo como respuesta! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El carácter lo consigues con: `\ell`

Recuerda que para hacer uso de este comando debes estar en un entorno matemático.

Comment: @Israel-ICM wat?

Comment: @Alfabravo, ups perdón creo que mi cerebro se cayó cuando hice esa revisión la verdad no la recuerdo 

Comment: Revisar [answer], saludos